# Parallel execution in a single ALU

Tags: parallel, cpu, alu, pipeline

I [read](https://www.quora.com/Is-an-ALU-able-to-calculate-multiple-operations-at-once-in-parallel-And-if-so-how-does-is-it-do-that-Is-there-some-kind-of-logic-gate-that-allows-this-or-what) that in theory, it is possible to use the circuits in an ALU in parallel. Now I am wondering whether there is any way to leverage this in practice *on commodity CPUs*?

Specifically, I want to design a function that can be pipelined very efficiently. Since I am free to define the (more or less arbitrary) computation steps of the function, I was wondering whether I can use pipelining on the ALU level, if I match each single step to a single circuit of the ALU?

Assuming that the register limits me to two times the word size of the CPU as input, could I still execute two instructions with half the word size in parallel?

Comment: Quote from quora link: So theoretically speaking, an ALU is capable of running multiple operations in parallel, such as an addition and multiplication, assuming those functional units exist and don’t share hardware (many ALU designs pass additions and substractions through a single adders). There's your answer. If your alu has only one logic block, then it can only do one operation at a time.

Comment: @Kartman Of course, though my understanding is that most CPU ALUs have multiple logic components, is this incorrect?

Comment: Is this using an existing CPU, or are you designing a new one?

Comment: From link: *Intel processor have for example 6 to 8 independent units and each of these units can do arithmetical operation (some are integer only, some are floating point) independently from another.* - it seems you haven't read that far? Also, asking for pointers is soliciting opinions and opinion based answers are frowned upon. This is a question and answer site.

Comment: @pjc50 I am speaking of commodity CPUs, I updated the question to reflect this, thanks!

Comment: @Andy aka Wow, I must say that I am a bit disappointed in the feedback. Obviously I did read that, which is exactly why I answered that I recall that there are multiple units on one CPU. I am sorry I failed to notice that I apparently read this on the same site. If you have any constructive input on how I can improve my question, please let me know.

Comment: We have fairly strict rules as to what constitutes a valid question and what doesn't; [help centre](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: If you're rolling your own on a large enough FPGA you can parallelise as much as you like.

Comment: If you send instructions through a processor and they aren't tying up resources, then you can use that resource with the next instruction. This is highly dependent on the processor. Many compilers already take advantage of parallel pipeline execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about existing CPUs, you're limited to what parallelism is exposed in the programmer's model. See [the rather nice diagram from Wikichip.](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(client)#Block_Diagram)

The constraint there is execution units. Each one accepts only one micro-op per clock cycle. (I'm not entirely clear whether they block on multi-cycle instructions or you can just keep feeding instructions in; the latter, probably).

That then means that you have to take the scheduler into account. For maximum efficiency, you'd want a mix of instructions that use different execution units, *and* have as long as possible between computing a previous result and requiring its result for the next computation so you're not stalled.

Note that this is over and above the parallelism available from SIMD instructions! So you could have a SIMD operation, an integer operation, a load/store all in flight at the same time.

Also note that if you really push this on a single core, continuously, it's quite possible that the processor will hit its thermal limit and throttle down the clock speed.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! So if I understand correctly, parallel (and superscalar) execution is indirectly possible on the Execution Unit level through the scheduler but (at least trivially) not on ALU level.

Comment: Yes, you the programmer have no way through the scheduler to get at individual bits of ALUs. You give the CPU a stream of instructions and it schedules them - getting maximum throughput with that is a complicated enough subject!

Answer (score 0):

Like @pjc50 says, you're limited to what the processor's instruction set lets you do. For most processors, there's no instruction to say "add a+b, and at the same time, multiply x*y", even if the hardware units for addition and multiplication were separate. On the other hand, for addition, subtraction and bit operations, they might not be, since two's complement subtraction is just addition with some bits flipped and carries set; and e.g. xor is just addition with carries inhibited.

In any case, executing an instruction also involves decoding the instruction itself, fetching the operand values and storing the results back, and the units available for those sets also limit what you can do.

However, commodity processors have been able to process multiple operations at the same time since at least the Intel Pentium (a superscalar architecture). Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P5_(microarchitecture)):

> The Pentium has two datapaths (pipelines) that allow it to complete two instructions per clock cycle in many cases. The main pipe (U) can handle any instruction, while the other (V) can handle the most common simple instructions.

Current CPUs have only increased in parallelism, and moreover, aren't limited to executing instructions in the order the appear in the code either. Considering that P5 is almost 30 years old now, you'd expect similar or better behaviour for many current processors, at least except the low end.  (IIRC, the earliest Atom processors didn't have much in the way of superscalar or out-of-order execution.)

That's in addition to any *explicit* parallelism you have in the way of so-called [SIMD instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) (single instruction, multiple data), which allow for doing e.g. addition of 8 values of 16 bits each within a 128-bit register (x86 SSE2) simultaneously at the same time.

---

In some cases, you *might* be able to use regular integer operations as parallel operations in a similar way. Bit operations are the easiest, a 64-bit and/or/xor is exactly the same as eight 8-bit operations in parallel. For addition and subtraction, there's the problem that a carry/borrow will cross the border between the bytes, but if you could still do eight *7-bit* additions at the same time using a regular 64-bit addition, just clear the 8th bit of each byte after (i.e. do `z = (x + y) & ~0x8080808080808080`). (Or four 8-bit additions, if you only use every other byte.)

This sort of makeshift SIMD may face problems with shuffling the data in the right places, but e.g. vector addition with 7 or 15-bit values could work. In practice, software-directed SIMD with bit granularity is sometimes used for [cryptography implementations](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30140/how-is-bitslicing-faster).

---

Given the variations and complexity in parallelism provided by different processors, it may be best to start by just writing your algorithm in the straightforward way, let the compiler handle the code generation in the way it knows best (e.g. the `-march` in gcc), use SIMD where available, and measure, test and profile different implementations to see which works best on the hardware at hand.